# When should I cache database query results when using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, caching

I know I should be using cache for queries that give the same result, when they queries are very heavy (big tables, many joins).

Notice I refer to **file based cache** and NOT memory(ram).

But what if for example, I have a filter in my application, that for example have 5 selects which are populated with most of the time, same data.

Each select is a database query that reads all data from a specific table.

So what is better?

- Read 5 different tables from MySQL (Let say up to 300 rows in each
  table) every time a user is loading a page? and let's assume we have
  many users (200+).
- Cache in a 5 different files those 5 different results, with let's say expiry of 10 minutes... And read the data from those files when loading the page for each user.

Comment: Rather than using a file, have you considered using either a key/value summary table in mysql, or a NoSQL database?  As for whether it's worthwhile to cache query results on disk at all, it would really depend on just how resource-intensive your queries are, to determine the tradeoff between that and maintaining the disk cache (be it nosql, straight files, or whatever).

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you want a disk cache rather than a memory cache because the results are unique to each user, so there would be a lot of data to cache?  (Otherwise the mysql query cache could potentially provide a quick 'fix'.  Not if you have more than a couple hundred megs to cache though.)

Comment: Anyway, to try to answer I would need significantly more info about the queries themselves.  The output of EXPLAIN and PROFILE for a sample query would help.  Just because queries involve large tables and many joins doesn't necessarily mean they will be particularly resource intensive if they're making good use of indexes.